# Text display (fonts) and icons size issues

Tags: 16.04, icons, fonts

Some application does not display text while there should be some and some icons are too bigs. I noticed this since I recently migrated to Ubuntu Xenial (16.04).

### Question

How to debug this kind of issues? Is there a way to trace how fonts are selected and displayed? Similarly, is there a way to trace how icons are choose and displayed? Are there any recommended clean‑ups in such cases?

### Examples

As three examples, `gnome-system-monitor` displays a big icon for the generic binary application icon, and `aconnectgui` (which uses FLTK) does not display any label, and `evince` fails to properly display a PDF which were readable in the past (the same if try to open this PDF in Opera browser). I previously noticed some applications I wanted to try failed to display text ; I initially though theses applications were broken and removed them all, but I ended to feel the issue is elsewhere, since it occurs with some others.

Although I noticed theses issues since 16.04, I just checked the issues exists with 14.04 also (I have both, using the same partition for `home`).

### Update

I remembered I have a `~/.fonts` directory managed with `font-manager` (not standard part of Ubuntu). If I rename this directory to disable it, then at least there is no text display issues any‑more. Still would be nice to be able to know what makes it fail. Similarly, I have an `~/.icons` directory filled with some icons to override the default ones and have some I lacks. If I disable it via renaming too, then there are no more big icons issues. This was not causing any issues before. I still know no way to debug it.

Comment: Install `unity-tweak-tool`, there you will see which configured fonts and icon sizes. Try to create a new account and login it, so compare behavior to yours. I think your account settings become harmed after upgrade.

Comment: @Redbob, I just edited the question with an update to tell about two suspected causes, but I still see no way to debug it.